# Left join Datetime columns from two tables concerning only date hours?

Tags: mysql, datetime, left-join, hour

Is there any solution to left join datetime columns by only DATE and HOUR.
At present i have situation that have left join by date and hours and minutes but i dont wont to concern minutes and seconds.

Comment: No. Coz minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you look in [MySQL DateTime function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour), you can make use of `DATE()` and `HOUR()`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 a
       LEFT JOIN Table2 b
           ON DATE(a.DateTimeColumn) = DATE(b.DateTimeColumn)
              AND HOUR(a.DateTimeColumn) = HOUR(b.DateTimeColumn)
```

This will join `2018-02-19 01:20:15` with `2018-02-19 01:45:50` disregarding the minute and seconds.

A *little caveat* in the performance though.

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6567d/1).